# Some of the major corrections are already in the thesis

Tags: defense

I've passed my viva with major corrections at a UK university.

Upon receiving the corrections, I found some of them were already emphasised and discussed in several places in the thesis.

My supervisor said I should just accept these corrections and work on them.

What should I do? Should I just expand with few sentences/paragraphs? Is it too bad to respond that they are already there?

Comment: What do you expect to gain by pointing out that these corrections were already there? You say "some", implying that some of the other major corrections aren't. So you will have to correct your thesis anyway.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi It's not easy to 'correct' something when you don't know why it's wrong. Contacting the internal examiner would help to clarify what aspect of what is already there needs changing. Guessing wrong could cause problems at this stage.

Answer (score 7):

Consider that if your examiners have asked you to add things that were already there, then either (a) they didn't read the thesis very well, or (b) those things that were already there were not clear or obvious. In the case of (b), you want to improve that.

You could reply to "defend" things as they are - but be very sure of your ground before doing so, and expect that the examiners might respond "change it anyway". Unless there is a good scientific reason not to do the changes, I wouldn't bother - as your supervisor said, just swallow your pride, and do what they've asked. While annoying, it'll be less trouble for you, and also not risk annoying people you might want to work with in future.